# How to deal with singularity when using stream variables in Modelica models?

Tags: stream, modelica

In the [Appendix D of Modelica Specification](https://specification.modelica.org/master/derivation-of-stream-equations.html), there are some situations of singularity when using stream variables, my question is:
In chapter D.3.2, if the `m1>=0`, then `inStream(h_outflow_2)=0/0`, but instead, `inStream(h_outflow_2)=h_out_flow_1` under any circumstances. Is this because the Modelica compiler would deal with this equation with symbolic manipulation first?

[image]

And in chapter D.3.4, when `m2>=0` and `m3>=0`, `inStream(h_out_flow_1)` would be undetermined, in order to solve this issue, there should be an equation `inStream(h_out_flow_1)=h_out_flow_1`. Is this equation generated by Modelica compiler automatically?

[[image]